# How to identify the user used DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD

Tags: php, facebook, messenger, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot using the messenger.
How do I know that the user clicked on my button

```
"buttons":[
  {
    "type":"postback",
    "title":"Bookmark Item",
    "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
  }
]
```

To receive am using the following code

```
if(preg_match('[hello]', strtolower($message))) {
$message_to_reply = 'Welcome';}
```

Answer (score 1):

When button is tapped, Facebook will trigger the [postback received callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback-received) and deliver the person's page-scoped ID (PSID). You can then present a personalized message to greet the user or present buttons to prompt him or her to take an action.

You can subscribe to this callback by selecting the messaging_postbacks field when [setting up](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#setup) your webhook.